# how to append words of two files word by word

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have two files with the same number of words and column fields in each line. I want to append these two files word by word. For example:

File 1:

```
A1 B1 C1
D1 E1 B1 C1
```

File 2:

```
A2 B2 C2
D2 E2 B2 C2
```

The output should be (the number of words should be respected):

```
A1_A2 B1_B2 C1_C2 
D1_D2 E1_E2 B1_B2 C1_C2
```

Comment: Is blank line between lines intended?

Comment: No No.. it is here for formatting. sorry. I have no blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

The **awk** solution:

```
awk '{
    getline a <"file2"
    split(a,A)
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        printf("%s_%s ", $i, A[i])
    print ""
    }' file1
```

**paste** + **sed**:

```
paste file1 file2 | 
sed '
    :a
    s/\(\(^\|\s\)[^_[:blank:]]\+\b\)\s*\(.*\t\)\(\S\+\)\s*/\1_\4 \3/
    ta
    s/\s*$//
    '
```

**bash loop**:

```
exec 3<file1 4<file2
while read -u 3 a ; read -u 4 b 
do 
    echo $(paste -d_ <(printf '%s\n' $a) <(printf '%s\n' $b))
done
```